# 2000's horror movie with a girl trying to escape with the help of a monstrous "guardian" creature

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

When I was younger probably in the early 2000's I remember watching this movie that I absolutely can not find what it is on the internet. It Was a long time ago, but I will tell you what I remember.

This movie was a horror movie about this young girl who I think was trying to escape from someone or some group of people who kept finding her and I believe they kept torturing her? Or maybe she just simply was found by 'bad' people.

I remember a scene where this doctor or someone from an institution was trying to inject the girl with something with bad intent but she managed to escape.
Another scene I remember is where she was in a warehouse with hundreds of other children who I believe were forced to work maybe? I remember her running into this smaller room and doing something that caused the building to catch fire.

The MAIN DETAIL that I believe will help identify the movie is that this girl had a 'guardian' monstrous creature named 'Artemis' who I believed helped her on occasion. The girl looked like she was around 8-12 years old with brown or black hair. I believe she was an orphan as well but certain. I don't remember her having any parents or family. I think the last scene was of her hugging 'Artemis' under a tall old bare tree. I think 'Artemis' looked sort of like a large version of when Remus Lupin turned into a werewolf in 'Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban'. 
Please help identify this movie! I live in America by the way.

Comment: Any other details you can recall? Language? Setting modern, or older? Any specific dialogue or actors?

Comment: I presume this monster was CGI? Otherwise you should be able to find it, there are about 40 movies after 1988 on IMDb with a character named 'Artemis'. Funny enough, there are zero between 1968 and 1988.

Comment: @Longspeak It was in English. I believe it was an older setting and I don't really recall any specific dialogue or actors. Sorry.

Comment: with the apostrophe's around Artemis, is that an allegation, or an implication?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like Stephen King's Kingdom Hospital (2004)
13 part TV series.
The creature in it was called Antubis.

Hope this helps :)

[image: The girl with her guardian]

Comment: Is that a giant ant-eater?

Comment: Yeah, well an ant-eater type creature :). It's actually Anubis but appears like this as its a misunderstanding from a child. More info about the creature here:) http://unofficialantubisfansite.atspace.org/index2.html